# How to implement HTTP request/reply when the response comes from a rabbitMQ reply queue using Spring Integration DSL?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to implement a HTTP request/reply using separate RabbitMQ queues in Spring Integration DSL. It's similar to [Spring IntegrationFlow http request to amqp queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077149/spring-integrationflow-http-request-to-amqp-queue). The difference is I want the response back to the original http caller. I could see the test http post message successfully passed to the request queue and transformed (into upper case) into the response queue. The message was consumed from the response queue as well but never returned back to the caller(http://localhost:8080/Tunner). Eventually the call timed out with 500 error. I am new to this so there could be something I totally missed. Could someone provide suggestion? The code is as follows:

```
public class TunnelApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TunnelApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${outboundQueue}")
    private String outboundQueue;

    @Value("${inboundQueue}")
    private String inboundQueue;

    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public TunnelApplication(ConnectionFactory factory) {
        rabbitConnectionFactory = factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue targetQueue()
    {
        return new Queue(outboundQueue, true, false, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue requestQueue()
    {
        return new Queue(inboundQueue, true, false, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter()
    {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate()
    {
        RabbitTemplate result = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
        result.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        result.setDefaultReceiveQueue(outboundQueue);
        //result.setReplyAddress(outboundQueue);
        result.setReplyTimeout(60000);
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sendReceiveFlow(RabbitTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Http.inboundGateway("/tunnel"))
                .handle(Amqp.outboundGateway(amqpTemplate)
                        .routingKey(inboundQueue)
                        .returnChannel(amqpOutboundChannel()))
                .log()
                .bridge(null)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow rabbitToWeb(RabbitTemplate amqpTemplate, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(connectionFactory, requestQueue()))
                .transform(String.class, String::toUpperCase)
                .log()
                .handle(Amqp.outboundGateway(amqpTemplate).routingKey(outboundQueue))
                .log()
                .bridge(null)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow replyBackToHttp(RabbitTemplate amqpTemplate, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(connectionFactory, targetQueue()))
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/tunnel")
                       .expectedResponseType(String.class))
                .log()
                .bridge(null)
                .channel(amqpOutboundChannel())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel amqpOutboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

We have also tried the following code (by my coworker) and we didn't get the response either:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class FlowConfig {

 

   @Value("${routingKey}")
   private String routingKey;

 

   @Value("${rabbitSinkChannel}")
   private String rabbitSinkChannel;

 

   @Bean
   public MessageChannel rabbitSinkChannel(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      return
         Amqp
         .channel(rabbitSinkChannel, connectionFactory)
         .get();
   }

 

   @Bean
   public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
   }

 

   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow httpFlow(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      MessageChannel rabbitSinkChannel = rabbitSinkChannel(connectionFactory);

 

      return IntegrationFlows
         .from(
            Http.inboundGateway("/sendreceive")
         )
         .handle(
            Amqp.outboundGateway(rabbitTemplate)
               .routingKey(routingKey)
               .returnChannel(rabbitSinkChannel)
         )
         .channel(rabbitSinkChannel) // or .handle? if so, what?

 

         .get();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following update works (I also removed the replyBackToHttp() method):

```
@Bean
public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate()
{
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    //result.setDefaultReceiveQueue(outboundQueue);
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyAddress(outboundQueue);
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(60000);
    rabbitTemplate.setUseDirectReplyToContainer(false);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyListenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    container.setQueues(replyQueue());
    container.setMessageListener((MessageListener) amqpTemplate());
    return container;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the almost complete solution to anyone that's frustrated and just wants to move on.

```
package com.scdf.poc.config;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.amqp.dsl.Amqp;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.http.dsl.Http;
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class FlowConfig {
   @Value("${rabbitSource}")
   private String rabbitSource;
   @Value("${rabbitSink}")
   private String rabbitSink; // Note: Has to be manually created in rabbit mq, the SCDF flows won't auto create this
   @Bean
   public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
      rabbitTemplate.setReplyAddress(rabbitSink);
      return rabbitTemplate;
   }
   @Bean
   public SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
      container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
      container.setQueueNames(rabbitSink);
      container.setMessageListener(rabbitTemplate);
      return container;
   }
   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow httpFlow(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
      return IntegrationFlows
         .from(
            Http.inboundGateway("/sendreceive")
               .requestPayloadType(String.class)
         )
         .handle(
            Amqp.outboundGateway(rabbitTemplate)
               .routingKey(rabbitSource)
         )
         .get();
   }
}
```

application.properties - note that SCDF uses the stream name as both prefix and suffix for queue names

```
rabbitSource=pocStream.rabbitSource.pocStream
rabbitSink=pocStream.rabbitSink.pocStream
```

SCDF stream definition for pocStream - this just echos the request back

```
rabbitSource: rabbit --queues=rabbitSource | bridge | rabbitSink: rabbit --routing-key=pocStream.rabbitSink.pocStream
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably misunderstood what is `returnChannel` on the `Amqp.outboundGateway` and try to rely your logic on it. Please, make yourself familiar with that Publisher Confirms and Returns feature: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#cf-pub-conf-ret.

It is also not clear what is a `replyBackToHttp` flow purpose, but it confuses at the moment with mixed references to other beans.

You probably need to investigate what is a request-reply configuration from Spring AMQP respective and you would probably don't try to use another queue for replies. Although it is still possible: see `replyAddress` property or `RabbitTemplate`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#request-reply

Comment: Thanks Artem! We will check the documents that you suggested. Well, we do need to use another queue for this. Actually our original intent was to use spring cloud data flow to replace our existing ESB soap services that required the request/reply. However, since SCDF streams are unidirectional, we have to add the Spring Integration part as suggested by Gary in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307078/spring-cloud-dataflow-for-http-request-response-exchange. Not sure if there're other ways that can achieve this purpose.

Comment: Correct. Spring Cloud Stream doesn't expose request-reply pattern since it doesn't not fit into streaming architecture. Of course, you always can use Spring Integration to fulfill your requirements as a part of Spring Cloud Data Flow processor implementation. You can have an AMQP Outbound Gateway (client) against fixed reply queue, but on the server side you should ensure that you carry a correlation headers properly between AMQP Inbound and Outbound Channel Adapters.

Comment: Hi Artem, I was able to make it work by updating amqpTemplate() method, adding a replyListenerContainer() method and removing replyBackToHttp() method. See my posted answer. Thanks for your help! The next step is to set up SCDF stream to test.