# How do I find the connection information of a RabbitMQ server that is bound to a SCDF stream deployed on Tanzu (Pivotal/PCF) environment?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

This is a follow-up question of [How to implement HTTP request/reply when the response comes from a rabbitMQ reply queue using Spring Integration DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392630/how-to-implement-http-request-reply-when-the-response-comes-from-a-rabbitmq-repl/66428887#66428887).

We were able to build the Spring Integration application and the SCDF stream successfully locally. We could send a http request to the rabbitMQ request queue which was bound to the SCDF stream rabbit source. We could also receive the response back from the rabbitMQ response queue which was bound to the SCDF stream rabbit sink.

We have deployed the SCDF stream into PCF environment which had a binding of an internal rabbitMQ broker. Now we need to specify the spring rabbitMQ connection information in the Spring Integration application properties - currently it's using the default localhost@5762, which is no longer valid. Does anyone know how to get this rabbitMQ configuration properties? We already checked the SCDF stream rabbit source/sink log files but couldn't find the information. I know we probably need to check internally whoever set up the SCDF/rabbitMQ in PCF environment, but so far we haven't heard the answers from them.

Also, it appears we can have a different approach that binds both the SCDF stream and the integration application to a separate rabbitMQ instance (instead of using the existing one bundled with the SCDF configuration). Is it a recommended solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear whether you're using the SCDF tile or the SCDF OSS (via `manfest.yml`) on PCF.

Suppose you're using the OSS, AFA. In that case, you are providing the right RMQ service-instance configuration (that you pre-created) in the `manifest.yml`, then SCDF would automatically propagate that RMQ service instance and bind it to the apps it is deploying to your ORG/Space. You don't need to muck around with connection credentials manually.

On the other hand, if you are using the SCDF Tile, the SCDF service broker will auto-create the RMQ SI and automatically bind it to the apps it deploys.

In summary, there's no reason to manually pass the connection credentials or pack them as application properties inside your apps. You can automate all this provided you're configuring all this correctly.

Comment: Thanks Sabby, we are using the SCDF tile as far as I know. However, I am not sure if I described clearly in my question or if I misunderstood you. Yes, you're correct that we didn't have to specify any of the rabbitMQ properties in creating and deploying the SCDF stream itself. We are asking about the rabbitMQ settings for the standalone Spring boot application (implemented with Spring Integration), which interacts with the SCDF stream's rabbit source and rabbit sink to send the request and receive the response.

Comment: For the app running outside of SCDF, you'd simply just bind your SI app with the desired RMQ service instance.

Comment: We have the SCDF PCF rabbitMQ service named "messaging-82830b13-4b0d-4f03-9b35-a8384c3670bb". Added the below properties but it didn't work (500 error). Is it correct?
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: ${vcap.services.messaging-82830b13-4b0d-4f03-9b35-a8384c3670bb.credentials.host:localhost}
    port: ${vcap.services.messaging-82830b13-4b0d-4f03-9b35-a8384c3670bb.credentials.port:5672}
    username: ${vcap.services.messaging-82830b13-4b0d-4f03-9b35-a8384c3670bb.credentials.username:guest}
    password: ${vcap.services.messaging-82830b13-4b0d-4f03-9b35-a8384c3670bb.credentials.password:guest}

Comment: I know it's been a while. Just wanted to update that "bind your SI app with the desired RMQ service instance" did work. We initially missed a configuration in .yml to specify the service type("rabbitmq" type). After adding that, it worked fine exception we're seeing some round-robin issue (strangely odd time calls work and even time calls fail), but it looks to be a different issue that we're looking to resolve.