# Why did we only receive the response half of the time (round-robin) with "Spring Cloud DataFlow for HTTP request/response" approach deployed in PCF?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

This issue is related to 2 earlier questions:

1. [How to implement HTTP request/reply when the response comes from a rabbitMQ reply queue using Spring Integration DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392630/how-to-implement-http-request-reply-when-the-response-comes-from-a-rabbitmq-repl)
2. [How do I find the connection information of a RabbitMQ server that is bound to a SCDF stream deployed on Tanzu (Pivotal/PCF) environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67007310/how-do-i-find-the-connection-information-of-a-rabbitmq-server-that-is-bound-to-a)

As you can see the update for the question 2 above, we can receive the correct response back from the rabbit sink. However, it only works half of the time alternated as round-robin way (success-timeout-success-timeout-...). The outside http app was implemented with Spring Integration showed in question 1 - sending the request to the request rabbit source queue and receiving the response from the response rabbit sink queue. This only happened in PCF environment after we deployed both the outside http app and created the stream (see following POC stream) there. However, it's working locally all the time (NOT alternately). Did we miss anything? Not sure what's the culprit in PCF. Thanks.

```
rabbitSource: rabbit --queues=rabbitSource | my-processor | rabbitSink: rabbit --routing-key=pocStream.rabbitSink.pocStream
```

Comment: Sounds like you have several instances of your stream in that PCF environment. This way there are more then one (round-robin feels like two) subscribers to the same RabbitMQ queue. Where only one consumer must be for that queue since only initiator of the request waits for reply, but odd (or even) replies go to different consumer of the same queue.  I don't place it as an answer, just because it is the best guess what is going on since you don't see a problem locally.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! What you said does make sense. The task now is to find the extra subscriber in PCF - a quick check didn't reveal it but we'll keep looking for it and let you know.

Comment: I think that could be something like auto-scalling in PCF. Sorry, I'm not familiar with app platforms.

Comment: Hi Artem, sorry I misled you. Just found that we're having the same issue locally - it used to work all the time. Could be some recent changes caused that. Still investigating,

Comment: Further investigate found that the problem is whatever the 2nd step of the stream is, it will always bind the rabbit source queue in startup (In our original stream, the 2nd step is a customized processor, we also tried to add a builtin "bridge" as the 2nd step, then bridge became the one to bind the rabbit source queue) - I guess that's what it's supposed to do - every next neighboring step has to bind the queue of the previous step for message passing? If so, does it mean we can't use the internal SCDF stream rabbitmq for the outside http app? Do we have to use a standalone rabbit server?

Comment: You probably need to think about changing type of the exchange for those queue to `topic` instead of direct which really makes it round-robin if that: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties. The `exchangeType` property. Also see exchange types in RabbitMQ docs: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html

Comment: Another good suggestion - I was thinking about the topic vs queue as well but didn't find how. Will try this a week later (on PTO now). Thanks!

Comment: Well, it appears the exchange type is already Topic by default. Not sure what else I can check other than if our recent change (either the standalone app or the stream itself) or the new upgraded SCDF version (3.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have several instances of your stream in that PCF environment. This way there are more then one (round-robin feels like two) subscribers to the same RabbitMQ queue. Where only one consumer must be for that queue since only initiator of the request waits for reply, but odd (or even) replies go to different consumer of the same queue. I don't place it as an answer, just because it is the best guess what is going on since you don't see a problem locally.

Please, investigate your PCF environment and how does it scale instances for your stream. There also might be some option of SCDF which does scaling for us.